# How to let webmail show html part of an email?

Tags: email, email-server, outlook, webmail, mime-type

I send an email which has a text mime part and a html mime part. When I receive the email using a client app such as Windows Mail, the html version of the email is shown in the client, which is good. However, if I login to webmail(such as outlook.com) to see the email, only the text part of the email is shown on the web page, the html part is shown as an attachment. How can I let webmail choose the html part as the preferred one?

Comment: Unless you attach the email structure to your question, answers can do little more than guess why one particular mail client might no chose to display the html part.

Comment: Can you see the html part if you send the multipart mime emails to other webmail(e.g. Gmail, Hotmail, etc.) recipients? Did you encounter the same issue if you configured these webmail accounts in the Outlook or Windows Mail application ? If you were still not able to see the html part, as **Dom** said below, it seems that Outlook/Gmail/Hotmail/etc. can't identity the mime html format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can not choose in place of the final user. If he wants to see in text, it will never see the html part. It is defined in the preferences of the software (at least for Roundcube).
Almost all the users see the mails in html.
If outlook.com is not displaying your email, check if you can see an external HTML email. Your mail is maybe invalid, and Outlook don't know the mime HTML part, and not display it.